# 2 columns. Merge duplicate values of A, sum duplicate values of B

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has 2 columns with data like this (from 1950 to 2015):

```
| Year   |  Count |
| 1994   |   10   |
| 1994   |   49   |
| 1994   |   2    |
| 1995   |   13   |
| 1995   |   6    |
```

I want my query result to be:

```
| Year   |  Count |
| 1994   |   61   |
| 1995   |   19   |
```

Things I have tried:

I began with a simple query like `SELECT SUM(Count) FROM 'population' WHERE 'Year' = '1994'` which was fine to bring a specific year but I wanted to **fill an array with the population of every year in the database.**

Doing something like `SELECT Year, SUM(Count) FROM 'population'` is closer to what I want except it just shown the first year only.

I'm not sure what terms I need to search up to get close to my answer. Union? I tried applying it but I just blerghed.

Comment: Use `group by year` with your last query...

Comment: Welp. That just worked. I feel silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
SELECT year,SUM(Count) FROM 'population' group by year
```